# Is it possible to evenly distribute the number of buttons in GridView?

Tags: android, gridview

In the adapter of the GridView I see that when the content layout is inflated it must contain a width and height. How do you evenly distribute the contents of a GridView so that the contents would take up equal amount of space?

For example I want to create an 3x3 square similar to this:
[image]

Also, I do not want the screen to be scrollable.

Comment: do you know the w+h of each cell's content beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're developing for API 21 and higher, `GridLayout` supports the concept of "weight", which may be familiar to you from `LinearLayout`. So you could give every cell these attrs:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_rowWeight="1"
android:layout_columnWeight="1"
```

And now your `GridView` (of whatever size you gave it) would be divided into three even rows and three even columns.

If you have to support earlier API levels, your best option is to use `ConstraintLayout`. With this strategy, you'd again give every child a width+height of 0dp, but now you'd set up chains of constraints so that each row was split evenly and each column was split evenly. Something like:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/child1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/child2"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/child2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/child1"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/child3"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/child3"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/child2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

Do the same thing in the vertical direction:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/child1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/child4"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/child4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/child1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/child7"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/child7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/child4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```